# Eclipse running in JRE but a JDK is required

Tags: eclipse, java

I always get the above mentioned error when i restart eclipse.I have gone through other posts in stackoverflow and understood how to resolve the problem( i.e by changing configurations in windows>prefernces and editing eclipse.ini file).

But the basic question is what is the meaning of that error?Someone please explain and also provide link to resource on how eclipse works internally with those preferences set.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Basically [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org) requires a Java compiler (javac) which is not part of a Java runtime environment. (JRE)  So it asks to use Java Development Kit (JDK) instead because JDKs are including a Java compiler.  Nearest explanation for this can be found in below link.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ for question "Unable to locate the Javac Compiler Error". How to force Apache Maven to use the Eclipse Java Development Tools (JDT) as its default compiler can be found [here](http://kthoms.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/using-the-jdt-compiler-in-normal-maven-builds/).

Answer (score 0):

The JRE runs Java applications. The JDK can also compile Java source code, which is what your Eclipse is trying to do.

Comment: Eclipse can compile without JDK, because it uses JDT to compiler Java application. The error mentioned above is about Maven, not Eclipse per se.

Comment: Does it mean maven plugin that is installed in eclipse is not able to compile using JDT? and who is compiling my code eclipse or maven?

Comment: I don't know in your particular case, but I do know that you need the JDK to compile.